# Removing items from an array in both directions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of times (these are not constant) `[1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00]`. The goal is to calculate times that can be bookable. If there is an existing booking from `4:00 - 5:00` then `3:00` should be unavailable as it would overlap the existing booking. To calculate this, I have a function that tells us the start and end indexes of the booking, I need to find a way to remove x times from **behind** the start index.

To make it more clear, I drew a diagram.

[image: problem diagram]

Doing this calculation will allow to calculate available times no matter how long the existing booking is. I'm trying to figure out how to create a function that does what I described. Below is the code I have to return the available times based on the start/end index provided however I'm stuck on how to approach the calculation I described above.

```
 // This filters times that are less than the start index
 const filteredTimes1 = availableHours.filter((item, index) => index < (
      (startTimeIndex || availableHours.length - 0)
 ))
 
 // This filters times that greater than the end index
 const filteredTimes2 = availableHours.filter((item, index) => 
     index > (endTimeIndex || availableHours.length) 
 )
 
 // Then combine the results into an array
 const validAvailableHours = [...filteredTimes1 , ...filteredTimes2]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Are we just removing the booking, and then the hour before the time the booking starts?

Comment: How is a 1-hour booking at 3:00 overlapping a 1-hour booking from 4:00-500?  I mean, they seem like they're _back-to-back_, but not overlapping.  One would go from 3:00 to 4:00 and the existing booking is from 4:00 to 5:00.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're right, I was using 1 hour bookings to make it more simple however in many cases the bookings are multiple hours

Answer (score 1):

You're way overcomplicating this.

Just keep a map of the times already booked, in this case 4pm.
Later add 3pm since you're adding that too.

Or if you want it simpler just use a Set.

```
const bookedHours = new Set()

// too add booked times
bookedHours.add(4)

// to get an array with available times
const available = [1,2,3,4,5,23,24]
const availableUpdate = available.filter(n => !bookedHours.has(n))
```

Comment: Booked times are stored as startTime and endTime. The problem is calculating how much time to remove before the start booking time when we know the duration of the booking.

Comment: You don't need an end time if you know how much each booking lasts, which in the case you posted is 1h

Comment: The duration is calculated by doing endTime - startTime. If startTime is 2:00 and the end time is 4:00 then we could do 4 - 2 = 2 which gives us a duration of 2 hours. Knowing this duration, I now need to remove 2 hours from before the startTime to prevent overlapping bookings.

Comment: Ok, you didn't communicate if event DURATION is any || set. If it's 1h || 2h || any for example.

One thing you could do is a filter on booked events
Then check endTime > bookedEvent.endTime
and also check startTime<bookedEvent.startTime && bookedEvent.startTime < startTime

Answer (score 1):

I mean you could simply use array.slice() to do the trick.

```
let allHours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let [startHours, endHours] = [4, 5];  
let duration = 1;

let availableHours = [
  ...allHours.slice(
    0,
    allHours.indexOf(startHours - duration)
  ),
  ...allHours.slice(
    allHours.indexOf(endHours + 1)
)]

console.log(availableHours)
```

Answer (score 1):

You alreay have a couple good answers. For fun, an alternate use I like to take for more advanced situations like a schedule etc.. make a schedule object and give it all the logic it needs to control the entire schedule.I added a few more features than you requested for fun, such as add time, remove time and set all available times.

```
const schedule = {
availHours: [],
responses: ['Appointment Confirmed', 'Time Not available, please choose 
another time'],
set addHour(hour) {
this.availHours = [...schedule.availHours, hour];
},
set removeHour(hour) {
this.availHours = this.availHours.filter((availHours) => availHours != 
hour);
},
set setHours(hoursArray) {this.availHours = hoursArray},
set request(reqHour) {
this.availHours.includes(reqHour) ? console.log(this.responses[0]) : 
console.log(this.responses[1]);
this.availHours = this.availHours.filter(
  (hour) => hour != reqHour && hour != Number(reqHour) + 1 && hour != 
Number(reqHour) - 1
);
},
};
```

I dont know the exact logic you need for your situation but this is just a general idea of how it can work. I chose to work in numbers only and add the :00 when I call anything that out puts a time.
heres a general example below of how it would function and log out

```
schedule.setHours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
schedule.request = 5;
console.log(schedule.availHours.map((hour) => (hour += ':00'))); //[ '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '7:00' ]  'Appointment Confirmed'
schedule.addHour = 8;
console.log(schedule.availHours.map((hour) => (hour += ':00')));//[ '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '7:00', '8:00' ]
schedule.removeHour = 7;
console.log(schedule.availHours.map((hour) => (hour += ':00')));//[ '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '8:00' ]
schedule.request = 12;
console.log(schedule.availHours.map((hour) => (hour += ':00')));// ['1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '8:00']  'Time Not available, please choose another time'
schedule.setHours = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
console.log(schedule.availHours.map( hour=> hour += ':00') ) // [ '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00','5:00', '6:00','7:00', '8:00','9:00', '10:00']
```

and finally, completely aside from above.. if you just want a function option different from the examples above, you can do something like this.

```
function openTimes(availTimeArray, reqTime = '') {
availTimeArray = availTimeArray.map((time) => time.replace(/:00/, ''));

return availTimeArray.includes(reqTime)
    ? (availTimeArray = availTimeArray
        .filter((time) => time != reqTime && time != Number(reqTime) + 1 && time != reqTime - 1)
        .map((times) => (times += ':00')))
    : (availTimeArray = availTimeArray.map((time) => (time += ':00')));
}

let availHours = openTimes(['1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00'], '3');
console.log(availHours); // [ '1:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00' ]
availHours = openTimes(availHours, '6')
console.log(availHours) // ['1:00']
```

If you pass no second argument it will just return all of the numbers in the array you give to the first argument. Also, if you define the availHours with let you can keep redefining itself by passing itself into the function to keep a running tally with one variable. The function could also be shorter and more straight forward if you only work in numbers and then add the :00 with map when you use the variable when displaying the hours, it's also only built to accept hours, not half hours.